# PR2, Indigo, will it be ever a thing?

Tags: pr2, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Actually this question is only for information. I just would like to know if it's in somebody's schedule to be working with the robot with the indigo version of ros. When I see the github repo, I don't see any *indigo-devel*, which is kind of saying that nobody is doing some work on it (but just want to be sure), mainly to take it into consideration for the future.

I know that for this to be done, the first thing to do would be changing the OS of the robot, since indigo is not supported on 12.04, then all dependencies, old to new ones, and lot's of extra things.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198964/pr2,-indigo,-will-it-be-ever-a-thing?/) by [silgon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4085/silgon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 649 on 2014-12-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [silgon](https://answers.ros.org/users/4085/silgon/) on 2014-12-05**:
I think that the people more involved are @ahendrix and @devonw. Thank you guys in advance ;)

It's been kind of a trending topic in some discussions with people in the lab here, that's why I ask.

**Comment by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) on 2014-12-05**:
@silgon I've got some insurity work to do on Hydro before I jump over to the Indigo development. Such as making sure all packages reach public (as you know from other thread ;-)) and working out the small bugs that users will report. I have scheduled to begin development February 2015.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Sligon,

This is Martin from Clearpath, @DevonW may be able to answer this question better than I, but we actually spoke about development on Indigo in the PR2 Community Call yesterday, as well as the overall state of PR2 software. You can find the recorded version of the call on our [PR2 support page under](https://support.clearpathrobotics.com/hc/en-us/categories/200217239-PR2) "Community Calls". If you didn't receive an invite for the community call be sure to sign up the PR2 Users mailing list and google groups! (Links to join are also found on our support page)

TL:DR We are planing to start Indigo development February 2015, but it is strongly encouraged to listen to the community call for the latest PR2 updates.

---

Originally posted by [MartinCote](https://answers.ros.org/users/20034/martincote/) with karma: 76 on 2014-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3